# How do I add existing comments to RDoc in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I want to format my existing comments as 'RDoc comments' so they can be viewed using `ri`.

What are some recommended resources for starting out using RDoc?

Comment: Take a look into the [Docs](http://docs.seattlerb.org/rdoc/)

Answer (score 16):

A few things that have bitten me:

- `:main:` -- RDoc uses only the last one evaluated; best to make sure there's only one in your project and you don't also use the `--main` command-line argument.
- same as previous, but for `:title:`
- `:section:` doesn't work very well

Answer (score 10):

RDoc uses SimpleMarkup so it's fairly simple to create lists, etc. using *, - or a number. It also treats lines that are indented at the same column number as part of the same paragraph until there is an empty line which signifies a new paragraph. Do you have a few examples of comments you want RDoc'ed so we could show you how to do them and then you could extrapolate that for the rest of your comments?